# Is virtual directory mapping supported in Websphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, web.xml, virtual-directory

Is there a way to create Virtual Directory that reside outside the Websphere Home directory. In other words, how do I map a web virtual path to a directory path.

e.g. C:/Test/image.jpg
accessible from: `http://localhost:9080/Test/image.jpg`

I know how to do this in Weblogic with the weblogic.xml file, but not Websphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this old question, it appears to be possible by using **extendedDocumentRoot** WebSphere extension

> extendedDocumentRoot 
>   Use the extended document root facility when
>   applications require access to files outside of the application web
>   application archive (WAR) directory. This facility enables you to
>   configure an application with one or more directory paths from which
>   you can serve static files and JSP files. You can use this attribute
>   when an application requires access to files that exist outside of the
>   web application archive (WAR) directory. For example, if several
>   applications require access to a set of common files, you can place
>   the common files in a directory to which you can link each application
>   as an extended document root directory.

from
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rweb_jspengine.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rweb_jsp_staticfile.html
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d870176c-c16c-4153-9f96-537116074b14

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do that using IHS(IBM Http Server) is just an Apache 2 configured with WebSphere plugin for load balance. There you can map all your static content.

Check: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/

regards.